# set Key bindings for specific applications in xmonad (or linux at all)

Tags: linux, google-chrome, key-bindings, xmonad

I wonder, is there a way to specify keybindings for specifical applications inside linux distro, xmonad specificly? Right now I'm doing it in my xmonad.hs config file like so:

`-- Start a terminal.  Terminal to start is specified by myTerminal variable.
  [((modMask .|. shiftMask, xK_Return),
     spawn $ XMonad.terminal conf)]`

The problem is I want set speciffical keybinding to work only in say chrome session. I tried chrome addons to change shortcuts but they don't worked out for me, so I want to remap those keys from xmobar.hs to original chrome shortcuts instead.

thx.

Comment: It's not quite clear to me what you're asking for. Do you want to press (say) mod-t while having chrome selected and this should become ctrl-t in chrome?

Comment: @deshtop I want to set arbitrary shortcut, not necesserely  with mod key, for it to input some key combination, but just inside of specific application (chrome in my case) - this means that this shortcut should not work anywhere outside of this app.

Comment: So this keybinding (from xmonad) should work only if chrome is the active window or anyway?

Comment: @deshtop yes, only if chrome is active window.

Comment: I haven't tested it but you might use `xte` to fake keyboard inputs which you can bind as keybindings in xmonad. Applying the keybindings only if the window name matches a string "chrome" requires more work - i'd guess thats possible but i have no implementation...